# Joomla Front-End User Editing Content in One Area

Tags: joomla, wysiwyg, frontend

On my website, I have an area where a user can create a team profile page. On the top of this page, is a header area that is 960px width x 170px height. This header, I would like to make a customizable area (like a user WYSIWYG) for the users. They must add an image, but I would like for them to be able to size this image and place it wherever they desire. They can also put text at whatever size and location in this header they want, if their image does not take up the whole header.

Does anybody know if this is possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, it's possible, but You will need to do some custom work for that kind of module. It is simple, but still i don't think You will find some free versions on JED

Comment: Hi Lanah, would you mind letting me know what type of idea you are thinking of? You say it is simple, but I am not sure even what direction to lean towards? And I am unsure of what to search for on JED, as I have definitely tried that already too.

Comment: You need to create module, where you will render team profile based logo with text. In your team profile component, create plugin for additional field with background and text area + add some js to backend for extra positioning and same js to frontend. Sorry for "simple" word, i'm hardcore professional programmer for joomla.

Comment: Ok, I understand where you are going with this. Thanks for your help